# SharePoint 2010, hotfix install fail "An error occurred while running detection"

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am having a lot of trouble installing hotfix 2849990 on my SharePoint Foundation 2010 server. After running it shows the error "An error occurred while running detection". I tried another hotfix as well but got the same result. I read on the web to do a "repair" but I cannot seem to access that. I attempting to run the install to get there, I click "Install SharePoint Foundation" a new window begins and I can see a new window open that reads "Please wait while setup prepares the necessarily files" Very shortly after this opens, it then closes and nothing else happens.

Anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried running the configuration wizard? maybe you have pending updates.

Comment: I haven't yet, but I will do this. Won't have any impact on my site, correct?

Comment: at this point, you need to be careful about doing anything. I cannot guarantee it will be fine, but it is supposed to be fine, as this is done after every update. if it fails the first time, do it one second time and it will likely to work

Comment: ok thanks. I tried, but still cannot run this update.

Comment: my next advice would be trying to run the setup from a command line. maybe you can see output that otherwise you can't. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262897%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: thanks. just to clarify. I should run the SharePoint setup? or the update setup?

Comment: your sharepoint setup appears to be broken and you need to repair it. run the main installer from command line and keep an eye for any relevant outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run configuration wizard

if that doesnt help, try to run the repair of the sharepoint setup using command line

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262897%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same issue now.
For those recommending to run **PSConfiggui.exe**, it wont allow because of pending updates. 
I am using the OPUtil.vbs script to repair my `c:\windows\installer` folder instead (Taken from a server where the CU installed as expected).
 It will rebuild the **installer** folder with the missing updates that cause the CU install to fail.